# leftover after upgrade impish -> jammy

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, ppa

After upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 it seems that I have several leftover packages.

When executing `sudo apt update` I get the following errors & warnings:

[image]

1. I think I do not need `http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu impish Release` and I' ve already searched for the "problem with Release file". But how should the command look like? Possibly:

   sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:flatpak/stable/ubuntu

This does not look good for me as it does not specify the impish release.

2. Why *jammy Release* does actually not have the release file?
3. What is `http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release`?

How can I see *apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details*. As that is what they recommend.

Additionally, in Software&Updates I had several checkboxes related to 21.10 which I deleted already, but there is a lot of staff which I'm not sure what is good for and if I should delete it. Especcially those saying "disabled on upgrade".

[image]

Comment: One of the important recommended steps of a release-upgrade is to review your PPAs and other Non-Ubuntu repositories BEFORE re-enabling them. Sometimes that software has been superseded by Ubuntu versions, and the non-Ubuntu repo is not needed anymore. Sometimes you simply don't use that software anymore. Unnecessary sources should be disabled (unchecked), of course. Also, keep in mind that Ubuntu has no control over non-Ubuntu sources -- they update when they wish, and some pay no attention to Ubuntu release cycles.

Comment: You seem to have a boatload of unnecessary PPAs. Sometimes this happens when new users read click-baity articles "*10 things to do after installing Ubuntu*" Those articles often include bad advice, like adding unnecessary PPAs that you must now clean up. Much of that software is available in the Ubuntu Repos (deb) and Snap Store (snap) without adding any new sources.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest answer is, since they were disabled on upgrade, you should untick the corresponding boxes to disable the PPAs until Jammy is (possibly) supported in the future.

The reason there is no release file is because the ppa isn't available for jammy. The last release available for the flatpack ppa is focal (20.04). The last release file for the teejee2008 ppa is impish (21.10).

You can visit [the flatpack ppa here](https://launchpad.net/%7Eflatpak/+archive/ubuntu/stable) and click the dropdown menu for "**Published in: any series**" where you will see the available Ubuntu releases. You can do the same for [the teejee2008 ppa here](https://launchpad.net/%7Eteejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

The good news is that both of these repositories may be updated in the future. It looks like the flatpack ppa is updated to include LTS releases and the teejee2008 ppa is updated for each release. Neither one of these has been updated for 22.04 (jammy) so only time will tell.

---

The following is a manual solution which really isn't necessary if you untick the boxes. However, it may help you understand what's going on under the hood.

**Manual solution:**

You can either manually edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/flatpack*` file(s) (or whatever their corresponding names are) and comment out the lines in each file or you can simply delete the flatpack files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

The same applies to teejee2008. Edit the corresponding file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and comment out the sources in the file or you can simply delete the file for now.

Comment: Ok. I've unchecked the boxes telling "disabled on upgrade". Should I also uncheck those refering to "impish" but not saying "disabled"? E.g. `*/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu impish`? Also what about those having (Source Code)? Do I need them as user?

Comment: @as5 You don't need the source code stuff unless you want to manually download and build or compile packages from source. Also, you don't need the source code stuff from impish. As far as the libreoffice ppa is concerned, you should leave the impish version disabled and [run the commands to install the ppa](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa#ppa-install) (click the link for instructions) to upgrade to the jammy version.

Comment: You will want to visit the other disabled ones to see if they have added support for jammy in the future. When jammy support is available, just leave the old version disabled and install the new version using whatever method is recommended by the maintainer (like the torproject repository).

Comment: If you are using Tor, I would recommend getting that taken care of sooner rather than later as updates for Tor are kind of important. If you don't really use it, it can probably wait.

Comment: Flatpak just released support for jammy https://launchpad.net/%7Eflatpak/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=jammy